# Are Connor and Murf more than just slippers?

Tags: welcome-to-demon-school-iruma-kun

In episode 3 of Welcome to Demon School! Iruma-kun we're introduced to Clara, who in turn introduces us to Connor and Murf.<sup>[1]</sup> At various points in time Clara talks to or about Connor and Murf.<sup>[1][2][3][4]</sup> They're referred to as slippers when Clara performs a move called *Slipper Kick*.<sup>[3]</sup>

At various points in the anime Connor and Murf move.<sup>[2][3][7]</sup> And so we know they are animate to some extent.

In the introduction the slippers appear in a backdrop with various green animals.<sup>[8]</sup> These green animals look like an un-slipperfied Connor and Murf. At a later point in the introduction we see a green animal scratching itself next to Clara.<sup>[9]</sup> I think Connor, Murf and the green animal are related, but I have no clue how. Interestingly in Episode 8 there's a backdrop with slippers, but no green animal.<sup>[5]</sup>

To me it looks like Connor and Murf are based on the green animal. Much like you can get Pikachu slippers that are based on Pikachu.

## Are Connor, Murf and the green animal related?

---

1. > I'm Clara!
   >   And my right foot is Connor, and my left foot is Murf!
   >   My familiar is Falfal!
   >   - Clara, Episode 3 @ 2:30
2. > Iruma: We need someone to play the husband and the cat.
   >
   > Clara: Connor and Murf can play them.
   >   Here you go!
   >   Say hi to them.
   >
   > Iruma: Hi...
   >
   > *Connor and Murf look at Iruma.*
   >
   > Iruma: Huh?!
   >
   > - Episode 3 @ 4:08
3. > Connor and Murf!
   >   Take this! Slipper Kick!
   >   - Clara, Episode 8 @ 3:27
4. > Ugh! All Iruma-chi does is play with Lady Redhair lately!
   >   No fair!
   >   I wonder how I can get Iruma-chi back.
   >   How Connor Murf?
   >
   > *Connor blinks*
   >
   > How, Sabro?!
   >
   > - Clara, Episode 8 @ 7:20
5. Backdrop of slippers without the green animal
   - Episode 8 @ 9:23
6. Clara's mom has a neck ornament that looks like the green animal.
   - Episode 8 @ 14:32, 15:58, 16:11, 16:29, 16:49
7. Connor and Murf both move Clara.
   - Episode 8 @ 17:44
8. [We see various slippers, and a couple of green animals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReuTl.jpg)
   - From 0:29 to 0:31 of the intro song.
9. [We see Clara wearing Conner and Merf whilst creating a lot of items. There is also a green animal in the background scratching itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4xzZ.jpg)
   - From 0:58 to 1:00 of the intro song.